# Why is "static" ignored?

Tags: c

```
 static enum RetType
        {
        SET_SUCCESS=0,
        SET_ET_ERROR = -1,
        SET_CBL_ERROR = -2,
        SET_SEN_ERROR = -3,
        SET_TAR_ERROR = -4,
        SET_ENG_ERROR = -5,
        SET_IO_ERROR = -6
        };

enum RetType ret = SET_SUCCESS;
```

I declare a static enum in global. But Visual Studio gives warning:

> warning C4091: 'static ': ignored on left of 'RetType' when no variable is declared.

Why does it ignore "static"?

Comment: Because you can only make variables static, not the type itself.

Comment: Because static is irrelevant/redundant in that contex. Typically a variable set to statisc is automatically assigned to the value 0 .

Comment: The warning tells you: *when no variable is declared.*

Comment: `static` is a storage class: they don't apply to enum definitions (and they would not apply to a struct or union definition either) where storage isn't allocated.

Comment: @ Steve Friedl So I can't hide an enum from other files? Right?

Comment: `static` is a property of a variable (or a function).   It is not a property of a type.   You are specifying it in a type definition.

Comment: @barbaros - I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here: an `enum` type definition is useful only when it's visible to a compilation unit. If you don't want some other dot-c file to know about the enum, then make sure it's not in any header file it includes. What are you trying to accomplish with this "hiding" ?

Comment: @Fureeish - This is C, not C++, so there aren't any classes

Answer (score 3):

As other's mentioned, static can only be used with variables (or functions). Basically "static" keyword is used to declare variables in data section of the process memory (and not on the stack). In your case, you are defining `RetType` globally as a type (and not the variable or function). Hence in you case you must:

```
enum RetType
        {
        SET_SUCCESS=0,
        SET_ET_ERROR = -1,
        SET_CBL_ERROR = -2,
        SET_SEN_ERROR = -3,
        SET_TAR_ERROR = -4,
        SET_ENG_ERROR = -5,
        SET_IO_ERROR = -6
        };
static enum RetType ret = SET_SUCCESS;
```

If you would like to declare `ret` statically. Here, `ret` is of type `RetType`, which is present in the .data section.

Answer (score 0):

Because its an enum definition, it doesn't make sense to make it `static`. You probably meant to do this instead:

```
typedef enum 
{
  SET_SUCCESS   =  0,
  SET_ET_ERROR  = -1,
  SET_CBL_ERROR = -2,
  SET_SEN_ERROR = -3,
  SET_TAR_ERROR = -4,
  SET_ENG_ERROR = -5,
  SET_IO_ERROR  = -6,
} RetType;

...

static RetType ret = SET_SUCCESS;
```